# application error on the web after you git push to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

Basically, after I git push to Heroku, my website throws an error called

> Application Error: An error occurred in the application and your page
>
> could not be served. If you are the application owner,
>
> check your logs for details.
>
> **But when I refresh the page, my website loads succesfully... Why?**
>
> For your information, I am running Hobbyist Dyno on Heroku with Rails

## HERE IS THE LOG:

```
git push staging master
heroku logs -t --remote staging



2017-01-10T19:07:34.332770+00:00 app[api]: Release v54 created by user xxx@gmail.com
2017-01-10T19:07:35.190813+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2017-01-10T19:07:35.191331+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2017-01-10T19:07:35.233553+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Restarting
2017-01-10T19:07:35.234020+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2017-01-10T19:07:35.995721+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-01-10T19:07:36.104550+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM


> 2017-01-10T19:07:36.082662+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
> 2017-01-10T19:07:36.121359+00:00 app[worker.1]: 4 TID-ow38ibptk INFO: Shutting down
> 2017-01-10T19:07:36.121553+00:00 app[worker.1]: 4 TID-ow38ibptk INFO: Terminating quiet workers
> 2017-01-10T19:07:36.122499+00:00 app[worker.1]: 4 TID-ow39cbrbg INFO: Scheduler exiting...
> 2017-01-10T19:07:36.623708+00:00 app[worker.1]: 4 TID-ow38ibptk INFO: Pausing to allow workers to finish...

> 2017-01-10T19:07:37.504392+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] === puma shutdown: 2017-01-10 19:07:37 +0000 ===

> 2017-01-10T19:07:37.504408+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Goodbye!
> 2017-01-10T19:07:37.800069+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
> 2017-01-10T19:07:38.127333+00:00 app[worker.1]: 4 TID-ow38ibptk INFO: Bye!
> 2017-01-10T19:07:38.345364+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
> 2017-01-10T19:07:42.226982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command
```

Comment: No that's not normal. Please observe the logs using `heroku logs -t` and see if there is something unusual. Post the logs here as well to help us solve the problem better.

Comment: @31piy I see... Not sure what I did wrong :( help me please! Attached is the log.

Comment: The log you've given are not sufficient. Please post the logs after you hit the app, and please don't attach image. Edit your post, and add the logs.

Comment: @31piy Sounds good! I will let you know when I'm done! :)

Comment: @31piy i just did!

Comment: @31piy thank you very much for your help in advance... I've been struggling.

Comment: Your app is getting timed out at the first hit. Is there something heavy you're doing on app boot?

Comment: @31piy I found a solution... :) Thank you for trying tho! It was assets pipeline and "spaghetti" js codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem was from my production.rb configurations. I used New Relic APM to help me narrow down which causes the timeout. Found out that it wasn't my middleware or backend. It was basically my assets pipeline problem.

### production.rb

```
config.assets.debug = true #I was setting it to true..
config.assets.debug = false #<- fixes the issue... Plus, I was putting unnecessary js codes in my application.html.erb
```

### Lessions learned...

I got to learn a lot about Sidekiq and thought it caused the problem lol and definitely New Relic APM is awesome in tracking which part of your code causes the timeout issue. In addition, try not to put too much js codes in one page...

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to resolve issues:

1. Test your site in local machine first, both in development and in production mode.
2. Run any pending migration on heroku by command: heroku run rake db:migrate
3. open heroku console and show logs in real time by command:
   heroku logs -t
   and hit the heroku link then you will display error logs.

Comment: I agree with you 100% and that's what I did! :D Definitely, try out New Relic APM tracking tool... It is freaking awesome...

Comment: yeah:) just request timeout... It wasn't in details... No any recognizable errors

Comment: Is your app running properly on local machine in production environment?

Comment: If you will not find errors then you can add a ticket to heroku support, they will help you.

Comment: If any process takes longer then 30 sec then request timeout H12 error is displayed.

Comment: yeah you are right :) but It wasn't timeout on localhost!

Comment: is there any process which takes more than 30 sec in local machine?
Request timeout error not getting on local machine.

Try to comment the code of longer process and test on heroku.